# xAxis.Categories does not works in highcharts when used with range selector

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working on using range-selector with column charts in Highcharts. By default, the data shown on the x-axis is Date/Time there, I want to set the values explicitly to be bind on the x-axis. To make it happen, I have set the xAxis property in the below manner, but it is not happening.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges','Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges','Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
}
```

Here is my  [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4z1v9yom/5)

Code:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges','Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges','Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        series : [{
            type: 'column',
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }],
        chart: {
            events: {
                redraw: function () {
                    //debugger;
                    //var start=$('.highcharts-range-selector').value();
                    //var start=$('.highcharts-range-selector').value();
                    var minDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
                    var maxDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)').val();
                    $('#a').val(minDate+"   "+maxDate);//=minDate+"   "+maxDate;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help.

Also, is there any restrictions on charts? that if we use range selector, we can't use other values?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The rangeselector works only with number xAxis, not categories.

Comment: please elaborate. share any working example with number xAxis but not the date